# what does the GM mean in xcode release

Tags: xcode, xcode6, terminology

I am new to xcode and ios development. recently I've seen the xcode releases with, for example **xcode 6.0 GM** and then **xcode 6.0**. I wonder what should we do with the GM or we need to wait until the non GM release in order to build ios app.

could anyone explain me about this ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Xcode 6.0 GM (Golden Master) is the version released before 6.0, and **it can be used to build & submit to App Store**, which is not possible with other betas.

This is necessary because apps should, ideally, **be updated before a new iOS is officially released**. Waiting for the official new Xcode would be too late, since it is always released with the new iOS.

Comment: can you update this answer for 2022, it there any GM version currently in 2022, or the latest at moment 14.2 will be considered the GM version