# Can apps be submitted in AppStore with Xcode 11 beta 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios13, xcode11

There used to be rule that apps built with beta version of Xcode can not be submitted for review. There doesn't seem to be anything in writing for Xcode 11 beta. Has the rule changed, and can we submit apps built with Xcode 11 beta?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: That's the problem, it will take couple of days for review.

Comment: Your app would be rejected during the upload if something is wrong, such as using an unsupported version of xcode.

Comment: It's not rejected, but its stuck in Processing in Testflight. AppStoreConnect has processed the build though.

Comment: Are you using TestFlight version 2.3? https://developer.apple.com/testflight/ *With TestFlight 2.3 on iOS 13 beta*

Comment: For TestFlight testing, yes it is approved. However for AppStore, I am not so sure.

Answer (score 1):

For TestFlight you can, however for AppStore you have to wait for `GM` version.
[What is GM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32184472)

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- Archive your app
- Open Organizer
- Select your archive -> Show in Finder
- Show Package Contents (Right Click)
- Products -> Applications ->
- Again Show Package Contents
- Open Info.plist
- Change "BuildMachineOSBuild" to one public build number, for example 18G87, build number of macOS 10.14.6
- Then you will be able to upload your app.

I have been doing it a lot of times during this beta so it is confirmed that it works.